# LyX - Copy/Paste Math Equations

Tags: latex, lyx

I am trying to Copy/Paste within Math Mode and it just pastes raw TeX code in the text area. I have looked at 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80133/copy-and-paste-of-mathematical-formulas-pastes-the-unformatted-raw-tex
and still cannot get it to work. I am using LyX 2.2.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

when you copy a complete expression you can paste it as is , but if you copy part of an expression (meaning you mark the inside of a math box and not the whole math box ) you need to paste it inside a mathbox

Answer (score 0):

Did you click inside the math area before pasting? `CMD-C CMD-V` worked for me!